# How to prove that the matrix is totally unimodular?

Tags: matrices, total-unimodularity, unimodular-matrices

I have the following matrix

$$A=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1\\ 1&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&1\\ -1&0&-1&0&-1&0\\ 0&-1&0&-1&0&-1}$$

By using Matlab, I believe it is a totally unimodular matrix. However, I am not able to prove this property. Does anyone give me some hints on this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Where does this matrix arise?  There are some applications that are known to produce totally unimodular matrices.

Comment: @saulspatz Dear Sir, I formulated a resurce allocation problem in an OFDMA-based network, which is an integer linear programming problem. I have no idea about  total unimodular matrix. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: That's okay.  I was able to prove it totally unimodular easily.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the matrix has a submatrix with determinant $\notin\{-1,0,1\}$ whose top row is a subrow of row $1$.  Since there is only one $1$ in row $1$, it must be the case that the matrix formed by deleting row $1$ also fails to be totally unimodular.  Similarly, we can discard the next $5$ rows of $A$ and we have only to prove that the resulting matrix (which I will also call $A$ for conformity with the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Common_totally_unimodular_matrices)) is totally unimodular.  The wiki says,

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix whose rows can be partitioned into two disjoint sets$B$ and $C.$ Then the following four conditions together are sufficient for $A$ to be totally unimodular:

Every entry in $A$ is $0, +1, \text{ or }−1$;

Every column of $A$ contains at most two non-zero (i.e., $+1$ or $-1$) entries;

If two non-zero entries in a column of $A$ have the same sign, then the row of one is in $B$, and the other in $C$;

If two non-zero entries in a column of $A$ have opposite signs, $B,$ or both in $C.$

In our (new) matrix $A$ we can let $B$ comprise the first $3$ rows and $C$ the last $2$ rows, and it is clear the the conditions are satisfied.

Comment: I am noticed that the first 6 rows form an unit matrix. From your post, it seems that we can always delete an unit matrix from $A$ and just show the totally unimodular of the rest of part. Am I right?

Comment: You can always delete a row or column that has at most one nonzero entry, by the argument I gave.  (Assuming all entries are in $\{-1,0,1\}$, of course.)

Comment: Thank you, Sir.

Comment: Think nothing of it -- my pleasure.